# in early am or at early am (time)

Tags: grammaticality, time, at-in

> Sexy, let’s go to AC for the whole night this or the following Friday night. We can leave around 8-9 pm and come back **in early am.**

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've heard it used as "in *the* early am". But it really isn't that much longer to use the much less awkward "early in the morning".

Comment: thanks, though it took me a minute to decipher your comment-- it's rather convoluted.

Comment: @vehomzzz: sorry! What I meant was I have heard it used as "We can ... come back in *the* early am", but I much prefer something like "We can ... come back early in the morning."

Answer (score 1):

In casual conversation (and since they called you *sexy*, I'll assume this is pretty casual), *am* (or *a.m.*) is used to mean *morning*.

So yes, this is correct.

Comment: By yes, you imply that I am only missing the article. And as previous poster suggested, it should be *"in the early am"*

Answer (score 1):

I agree with other posters - "a.m." can be used, jocularly, as an exact substitute for "morning".  So if you want to use it like this, check that your sentence still sounds right if you swap out "a.m." and swap in "morning".

It's all very slangy of course :D